# Generate map tiles with custom data already printed

Tags: leaflet, data-visualization

I'm using Leaflet, with CanvasLayer, to draw a large dataset on a map. Each data point is rendered as a circle with a radial gradient fill, gradient colors depending on each point's data values (4 color for each point).

Data was dynamic at first, but now it became a fixed set of (>1M) points.
What would be a way to draw the data once, save tiles, and then serve them with added data already "printed" on them?
I ideally would like to, for a set of zoom levels, get all the tiles for the interested area, run my draw function (so that I can draw a different gradient for each data point), and finally export tiles with my drawing applied.

Comment: The answer is [yes](https://jdebp.eu/FGA/questions-with-yes-or-no-answers.html), but your question is too broad, and there are several approaches. Consider researching about server-side rendering via Geoserver, Mapserver, Qgis server, mapproxy or other similar tools.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up drawing my dataset on tiles with [node-canvas](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas). This way I can make a TileLayer in Leaflet which works as an overlay on whatever map I want to render underneath.

node-canvas was the answer for me, because I could use it to draw data the way I wanted, like I would do on an html canvas. Then it was a matter of figuring out tiles and zoom levels:

1.
I used https://github.com/veltman/xyz-affair to know on which tiles my data would fit at a selection of zoom levels

2.
For each zoom level, I've drawn my complete picture (whose size I knew from step 1) and saved each 256x256 region of it as a png tile

3.
I can now serve my static tiles with a web-server, to get them on Leaflet as a TileLayer